# Why is an explicit type conversion whose type-specifier is void and the initializer is non-empty braced-init-list invalid?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

```cpp
int main(){
   void{1,2}; // #1
}
```

`#1` is complained be [invalid](https://godbolt.org/z/se8fxxKfv) by both GCC and Clang. However, from the point of grammar, it may be valid.
[expr.post#general-1](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.post#general-1)

> simple-type-specifier braced-init-list

The grammar does not restrict what the `braced-init-list` should be. From the point of the relevant rule, it also does not have any statement for this case
[expr.type.conv#2](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.type.conv#2)

> If the initializer is a parenthesized single expression, the type conversion expression is equivalent to the corresponding cast expression. Otherwise, if the type is cv void and the initializer is () or {} (after pack expansion, if any), the expression is a prvalue of type void that performs no initialization. Otherwise, the expression is a prvalue of the specified type whose result object is direct-initialized with the initializer. If the initializer is a parenthesized optional expression-list, the specified type shall not be an array type.

From the point of definition of the initialization, it states that
[dcl.init#general-14](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#general-14)

> The initialization that occurs
>
> > - in a functional notation type conversion

Since a prvalue of type void performs no initialization and does not have a result object, hence the whole [dcl.init.list#3](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.list#3) is not suitable here

> List-initialization of an object or reference of type T is defined as follows:

The case cannot even be caught by [dcl.init.list#3.12](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.list#3.12)

> Otherwise, the program is ill-formed.

So, I wonder Is any rule states that `void{1,2}` should be considered ill-formed?

Comment: "The case cannot even be caught by dcl.init.list#3.12" - Why not? It seems that this is exactly what applies, since none of the previous points apply.

Comment: @SebastianRedl It appears to me that be caught by [dcl.init.list#3.12] if the case firstly satisfies the condition >> *List-initialization of **an object or reference** of type T is defined as follows:* << What is the object here? no result object corresponds to a prvalue of type void. Moreover, a prvalue of type void performs no **initialization**, so how could we use the rule for initialization to judge whether the case is valid or not?

Comment: Interesting. I agree that this clause prevents application of 3.12. Seems like a defect in the standard, though; I'm pretty sure it's *meant* to apply.